# Web Forms Multiple Drop Downs With Same Source

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I need to use the same datasource for a dynamic amount of dropdown lists.

I'm basically displaying a table from my database in an editable table via repeater.

I can't figure out how to bind my datasource to the multiple dropdowns.

I know that I haven't hooked up any postbacks yet (in code below) but I have done this before just never with a dropdown.

Oh and one final requirement is that the default value of each dropdown should be based on the data the repeater is databound to.

Any ideas on how I can get these asp:DropDownLists databound?

I have this in my codebehind and was hoping to use it as the datasource.

```
private DataTable _pages;
protected DataTable Pages
{
    get
    {
        if(_pages.Rows.Count == 0)
            return Page_Listing();
        return _pages;
    }
}
```

Here is the repeater which I already have databound:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Cycle_DataList">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="GridItem <%# Container.ItemIndex % 2 == 0 ? "rowOdd" : "rowEven" %>">

                    ..........

                    <span class="internal">
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="Internal"
                            class="hiddenText"
                            Text=''
                            runat="server"
                            Checked='<%# String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Eval("INTERNAL_MENU").ToString()) ? false : true %>'
                            GroupName="menus"
                             />
                    </span>                        
                    <span class="external">
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="External"
                            class="hiddenText"
                            Text=''
                            runat="server"
                            Checked='<%# String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Eval("EXTERNAL_MENU").ToString()) ? false : true %>'
                            GroupName="menus"
                             />
                    </span>
                    <span class="page">
                        <asp:Label ID="Page" runat="server" title="Info Page"><%# Eval("REG_INFO_PAGE") %></asp:Label>
                       I WANT THIS LABEL TO BE A DROPDOWNBOX INSTEAD
                    </span>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

[image]

Comment: you may use OnRowDataBound event, and bind the data using codebehind?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (replace your datasource ID and column name)

```html
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Info Page">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlInfo" runat="server" DataSourceID="YourDataSourceID" DataTextField="ColumnName"></asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I no longer have access to this code base.

Comment: I meant replace in your aspx code with your data source names.

Comment: I understand but I don't have access to that code anymore. This question was from April!